# when is super(Baseclass, self).__init__ used

Tags: python, class, super

When should the following code be used in Python
(Assume that Baseclass inherits from Parent class and Parent class has some variables initiated in **__init__**() method)

```
class Baseclass(Parent):
    def __init__(self, some_arg):
        self.some_arg = some_arg
        super(Baseclass, self).__init__()
```

Does this code makes all the local variables defined in **__init__** method of Parent class accessible in Baseclass? What significance does it make?

Comment: What do you mean with "variables definied in __init__"? Do you mean instance attributes or local variables?

Comment: i mean local variables such as self.some_variable = some_variable

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`super` keeps your code from being repetitive; a complex `__init__` needn't be c/p'ed into your inheriting classes. It also makes MRO work as it should, such that if you use multiple inheritance it will work correctly.

One reason to do this would be to ensure that all of your inheriting objects have certain attributes which they don't have from the parent. If you simply write a new `__init__`, they won't have them unless you repeat your code. For example:

```
>>> class A(object):
...     def __init__(self, x):
...             self.x = x
... 
>>> class B(A):
...     def __init__(self, y):
...             self.y = y
... 
>>> Stick = B(15)
>>> Stick.x
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'B' object has no attribute 'x'
>>>
```

Without calling `super` during the `__init__` the entire method is simply overridden. A call to `super` here ensures that both variables exist in the inherited class.

```
>>> class C(A):
...     def __init__(self, x, y):
...             super(C, self).__init__(x)
...             self.y = y
... 
>>> Dave = C(15, 22)
>>> Dave.x
15
>>> Dave.y
22
>>>
```

Note that in the `super` call, `x` is passed to the `__init__()` call, but `self` is taken care of in the `super(C, self)` part of the code.

EDIT: TyrantWave also rightly points out that `super` is also quite useful outside of `__init__`. Take an object with a simple `foo` method for example.

```
class Parent(object):
    def foo(self):
        return "I say foo!"
```

The inherited class may want to just alter the output of this function instead of totally rewriting it. So instead of repeating ourselves and writing the same code over again, we just call `super` to get the parent's return value, then work with the data and return the child class's modified results.

```
class Child(Parent):
    def foo(self):
        parent_result = super(Child, self).foo()
        return "I'm a child!! %s" % parent_result
```

In the above, the call to `super` returns the `Parent`s value for `foo()` and then the `Child` goes on to work with the data further before returning it themselves.

```
>>> Alan = Parent()
>>> Stan = Child()
>>> Alan.foo()
'I say foo!'
>>> Stan.foo()
"I'm a child!! I say foo!"
>>>
```

Comment: Also to note, you don't just have to call `__init__` from `super`. `super(B, self).func(args)` will call `func` from `A` with `args`.

Comment: That's true and it's a good use example -- I'll update my answer to include that